# CvException on OpenCV4Android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I try to get my ROI using clicking on the screen. This is the part where the error occur.

```js
@Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        Mat roi_mat = new Mat();

        if (startX!=0 && endX!=0){
            //Toast.makeText(this, "start:"+start_point+"   end:"+end_point, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Core.rectangle(rgba,start_point,end_point,border_colour,0,8, 0 );
            roi_rect = new Rect(startX,startY,(endX-startX),(endY-startY));
            Mat roi_mat_ref = new Mat(rgba,roi_rect);
            roi_mat_ref.copyTo(roi_mat);
            //rgba.copyTo(roi_mat);

        }
        return rgba;
    }
```

Everything is okay when running the application. But when i want to get the ROI, it show an error.

> 10-04 20:19:18.754    6794-6859/com.example.tew.roi E/cv::error()﹕ OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= _rowRange.start && _rowRange.start <= _rowRange.end && _rowRange.end <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Range&, const cv::Range&), file /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 284
>
> 10-04 20:19:18.755    6794-6859/com.example.tew.roi E/org.opencv.core.Mat﹕ Mat::n_1Mat__JIIII() caught cv::Exception: /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:284: error: (-215) 0 <= _rowRange.start && _rowRange.start <= _rowRange.end && _rowRange.end <= m.rows in function cv::Mat::Mat(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Range&, const cv::Range&)
>
> 10-04 20:19:18.755    6794-6859/com.example.tew.roi W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fbf258)
>
> 10-04 20:19:18.756    6794-6859/com.example.tew.roi E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3348
>
> CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:284: error: (-215) 0 <= _rowRange.start && _rowRange.start <= _rowRange.end && _rowRange.end <= m.rows in function cv::Mat::Mat(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Range&, const cv::Range&)
>       ]
>
> at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
>
> at org.opencv.core.Mat.(Mat.java:676)
>
> at com.example.tew.roi.MainActivity.onCameraFrame(MainActivity.java:154)
>
> at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:387)
>
> at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:346)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

[This is my full coding.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c0QNodGHw0liwSmlc2EM0G0FZC-JW_-gJ4I4f6OqdWw)

Answer (score -1):

Adjusting the EndX-StartX values seems to work for me. You can try reducing it a bit before sending it to Mat.

Comment: Your answer lacks some in depth explanation, why your proposal resolves the OP.